# How to sort data frame by timestamp for multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Edit: I have managed to organize the index properly of my df, along with the data being added into the correct columns. However, the append function continues to add rows instead of placing data in the row corresponding with its index value/date of entry.

[image of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGueW.png)

As you can see here, each append creates a new row instead of placing it into the corresponding column at the correct row.

```
comp_holder = []

titles = []
i = 0
for value in names:
    titles.append(names[i])
    i+=1

#Number of Articles and Days of search
num_days = int(end) - int(begin) + 1
num_arts = len(titles)

arts = 0
days = 0


#Sets index of dataframe to be timestamps of articles
for days in range(num_days - 1):
    comp_dict = {}
    comp_dict['index'] = int(int(page_list[0]['items'][days]['timestamp'])/100)

    comp_holder.append(comp_dict)



#Adds views per day to correct column of dataframe, corresponding to article name
arts = 0
days = 0
for arts in range(num_arts):
    for days in range(num_days - 1):
        comp_dict = {}
        comp_dict[titles[arts]] = page_list[arts]['items'][days]['views']
        comp_holder.append(comp_dict)

comp_df = pd.DataFrame(comp_holder)


comp_df
```

Is there another function I could use to add to existing rows instead of appending them all?

Comment: It would be better if you could post the code here?

Comment: did the images not post?

Comment: I mean you can add the code in your post as formatted text? That may help others in debugging it.

Comment: ok hows that? Should be up now